# iOS Safari fails to send form data via AJAX

Tags: javascript, ios, ajax, forms

I'm trying to submit a form via Ajax with JavaScript. It works on IE, Firefox, Chrome and iOS in Browserstack, but it doesn't work in iOS Simulator or a real iOS device or desktop Safari.

I've tried `XMLHttpRequest onload` and `XMLHttpRequest onreadystatechange`, neither gets triggered. As far as I can tell `request.open('POST', url, true);` isn't working. `console.log('2');` never gets triggered either.

I added this for debugging:

```
request.send(data);
console.log(request);
setTimeout(function(){ console.log(request); }, 3000);
```

They both return *readyState: 1* in Safari, in other browsers the first one returns *readyState: 1* and the second one returns *readyState: 4* as expected.

Here's my code pared down to the essentials:

```
$('.ajax-form').submit(function(event) {
  var form = event.target;
  var data = new FormData(form);
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var method = form.getAttribute("method");
  var action = form.getAttribute("action");
  var url = window.location.href
  request.open('POST', url, true);
  request.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");
  request.setRequestHeader("HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH", "XMLHttpRequest");
  request.setRequestHeader("pragma", "no-cache");
  console.log('1');
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    console.log('2');
    if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) {
      var response = JSON.parse(request.response);

      if (response.success && response.finished) {
        // Go to selected success page
        window.location.href = $(form).find('[name="formReturnUrl"]').attr('value');

      } else if (response.errors || response.formErrors) {
        // Deal with errors
      }
    }
  };

  request.send(data);
  console.log(request);
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(request);
  }, 3000);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

All my iOS testing is on iOS 11 in Safari. I've read a few things about iOS being weird, but I haven't found a solution that works for me. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know why this is happening but I recommend trying `$.post()`, since you're already using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but jQuery Ajax isn't correctly returning form error data from my CMS (Craft running Freeform). I'm trying to use pure JavaScript for the Ajax since that works perfectly in my environment, except in iOS Safari... Any other ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved. Thanks to @mxcoder for pointing me in the right direction.

Safari (desktop and iOS) have a bug when creating FormData with empty file fields. I solved this by disabling empty file fields right before creating FormData and then re-enabling them right after so the form can be reused after the Ajax is submitted.

I changed `var data = new FormData(form);` to this:

```
// Disable empty file fields before submitting.
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1) {
    var $inputs = $('input[type="file"]:not([disabled])', form);
    $inputs.each(function(_, input) {
        if (input.files.length > 0) return
        $(input).prop('disabled', true);
    });
}

var data = new FormData(form);

// Re-enable empty file fields after creating FormData.
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1) {
    $inputs.prop('disabled', false);
}
```

1. If the browser is Safari, disable empty `<input type="file">` elements
2. Create FormData
3. If the browser is Safari, re-enable empty `<input type="file">` elements. This allows the form to be reused after successful submission or after correcting errors.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem, Safari is indeed tricky sometimes.

I don't have a solution yet for you but can you try the following:

1. Try not using FormData, maybe iOS doesn't play nicely with XHR + FormData yet, it could be a bug worthy to report!
2. Can you share the request and response body and headers? Maybe there's something in the server side failing for the iOS request, again, maybe some misplaced header.

Comment: 1. I'm a little new to JavaScript Ajax. What would I do instead? 2. The little data pinwheel by the wi-fi icon spins after I click the submit button, but the web inspector never shows any network activity. Seems like desktop Safari has the same problem.

Comment: on 1, you can try for now something simple, like: `xhr.send("foo=bar&lorem=ipsum"); ` just comment out the usage of FormData, to validate if you're getting blocked by an iOS bug with it.

Comment: That seems to work. Now how should I replace FormData?

Comment: Well, you can always use jQuery `serialize` method, it takes a form and spits out a string with the form values as URL params.